US Treasury Trading Hours and vol
I have an exercise to convert US Treasury daily vol to hourly vol. The question now is how many hours should I count for a day for US Treasury? A relevant if not exact question is what the trading or actively trading hours are for US treasury ?
what is your opinion

US Treasury trading is OTC so there are no official trading hours.  However in practice , trading in NY ends around 5pm, and there is about a 2 hour gap until trading opens in Tokyo.  Hence trading is almost 24 hours.  Converting to hourly vol by dividing by $\sqrt{24}$ however would be naive.  Most of the volatility occurs in NY morning, especially on days when important economic data is released .

In my impression 8am to 5pm NY are the most important trading hours. As mentioned the 8:30am government announcements can have a big impact. Someone once said "trading bonds is an early business". By comparison the NYSE (i.e. stocks) only opens at 9:30.
